# Use ProxyPass and JkMount simultaneously

Tags: apache, http, proxy, mod-proxy, mod-jk

I want to send all request from localhost to another server and specific request that start with this pattern `/*/service/*` to ajp server and I use this configuration in apache http server but always all the request send to first server `(http://172.16.65.83:8080/)`, How can I get the rid of it?

```
ProxyPass / http://172.16.65.83:8080/
JkMount /*/service/* loadbalancer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ProxyPass itself to bypass to other server.

```
ProxyPass           /service !
ProxyPass           /service       ajp://localhost:9009/
ProxyPassReverse    /service       ajp://localhost:9009/
ProxyPass           /              http://172.16.65.83:8080/
ProxyPassReverse    /              http://172.16.65.83:8080/
```